# Host Server relocation procedure

Tags: dns, server, domain-registration, ip-address, webserver

I have this technical issue below...

We have this domino server in our DMZ that hosts multiple websites. This server has a public ip x.x.x.x.

Now we are asked to move this server away from our network for security reasons. We decided to move it to our ISPs premises.

These are the facts. Now what are our options? Do we need to go separately to all registrars (of the domains hosted) and change x.x.x.x to the new ip y.y.y.y ? Or is there a way to redirect traffic from x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y directly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you move the server, get the IP address that the ISP will assign to you to use. Just as you shut the server down to move it, update your DNS entries (likely with your registrar) to the new IP address and install the server at the new location.

There will always a lag-time as DNS servers propagate your DNS settings to the other DNS servers accross the Internet (anywhere from immediately to 48 hours), however, your downtime should be as short as possible.

BTW- I used to be a webhost and registered ISP. This should work a peach.

Comment: You see, there are many domains hosted on the server. Should I go to every different registrar and update the DNS entries? Isn't there a more efficient way to achieve this redirect of trafic?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Unfortunately, there is no short-cut for that. You will have to update all the domain names with the registrar for each. It does not take too long. I updated about 30 a couple of years back and it only took a short while (much less than an hour I am sure). It may help to organize this process with registrar URLs, usernames, and passwords in a text document ahead of the move to help save time.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy My pleasure! I have been through this enough times. At one point, I had over 300 domain names I managed for customers and even moved them from one registrar to another and one network to another. It takes a bit of work, but it should not be too bad.

Comment: That's why you should use a service like Zerigo.com to manage your DNS. You can setup separate accounts for clients if you like but add your email address as an admin on all of them. Then they appear in one interface and changing IP addresses is a simple copy and paste matter - once setup any changes on 30 domains would take only minutes to do. Plus you get all the benefits of a rock-solid DNS system and the changes happen in realtime - no waiting for DNS propogation. I don't like being tied to an ISPs infastructure.

Comment: @garth I have never heard of this service. Nice to know! Thanks!! If I remember right, GoDaddy did finally add an option to update domain names in bulk. I no longer maintain too many domain names. I shutdown my hosting business and officially retired from the IT world (with little success since I keep mucking around with IT research) in the early 2000's. Cheers!

Comment: @closetnoc yes i've looked at your closetnoc site. I too built & ran an ISP but sold it around 2000. Forgotten more than I ever learnt :-) Still got hundreds of domains that I manage - tried to retire but it didn't work out for me. Early new year I'm thinking of moving them all to DigitalOcean setups once I learn DO's methods.

Comment: @garth Oh no!! :-o My site sucks! It is embarrassing. It is mostly experimental and how I know certain things I write here. I do have new and updated stuff I am working on, but not hardly at all. I spend more time here than I do working on anything of my own. I am busy with the homestead, antiques business, as a property manager (my own rentals), etc. After the holidays, I should have more time since nothing grows in the winter. ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc yeah I've got site "skeletons" in my closet too. Stuff I haven't touched for years. So you are currently doing the security research you mentioned on the site?

Comment: @garth Yes. Though a lot of it has dried up these past two years. Mostly it is a support role by providing Internet hacker information, back-end processes, data pattern matching, code specific solutions, attack methodologies/patterns, etc. Much of it infrastructure based meaning power grid, gas, oil, water, banking, etc. where there are several protocols at play. But as part of it, I have my own pr*ck list of people hacking, scraping, and spamming my sites. I have a ton of data I cannot effectively display yet. I am still working on it. With over 70 tables, I have more db schema work to do.